# Android - Random not working

Tags: java, android, random

I'm new here so please go easy on me. I've just started fiddling with android development and for a first app I'm trying to do a press a button->get a random sentence. My idea is to have 2 activities: The main one where you press the button, it choses a random number and apends it to an intent to be sent to the other activity (like shown below).

```
public void activity2(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, RandomThought.class);
    Random rand = new Random();
    String x = Integer.toString(rand.nextInt(3));
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_RANDOM, x);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

The other activity then receives it and chooses a sentence from the XML strings file in the following way:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String x = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_RANDOM);
    int a = Integer.parseInt(x);
    switch (a){
        case 0:
            send = getString(R.string.random0);
        case 1:
            send = getString(R.string.random1);
        case 2:
            send = getString(R.string.random2);
    }

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setTextSize(40);
    textView.setText(send);

    setContentView(textView);
```

Now, for some reason what is actually happening is that it is chosing always the higher amount possible (in this case 2). Also, considering the life-cicle of an activity, if I go back into the main activity and I press the button again will it generate the new number and sentence or do I need to define a similar situation on the onResume()/onRestart() methods?

Comment: Have you tried to log the random int in `activity2`?

Comment: Why are you converting the int to a string, just do convert it back in the second activity?

Comment: As I stated, I just started playing around with this and the putExtra method was asking me for a string so I did that. Though now I realize I can probably just do the random generation on my second activity.

Comment: `putExtra()` also takes `ints`. Just try it ;)

Comment: It in fact does but how do I get it on the other end? The getStringExtra method complains about type mismatch. Is there another method to gab ints form the intent?

Comment: `getStringExtra()` is for strings, so...`getIntExtra()` is for `ints` ;)

Comment: I tried that but then it asks me for another parameter and I don't understand what that parameter should be. I'll look up the documentation on that. Thanks for your help :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use `break` within your switch

Comment: Thank you. I feel so incredibly dumb now >.<

Comment: @user3288104 happens to the best of us

Answer (score 1):

Your issue isn't related to the random generator. You just forgot to put `break;` at the end of your `switch` cases :

```
switch (a){
    case 0:
        send = getString(R.string.random0);
        break;

    case 1:
        ...
}
```